# Selecting diode with Vf~300mV at 100uA forward current for reproducing a zero crossing published TI circuit

Tags: diodes

I would like to build for educational purpose the circuit described [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa542/sbaa542.pdf?ts=1692976579184).

[image]

I hit a snag for selecting diodes D1 and D2.

The author of the paper recommends:

> Select the anti-parallel diodes. Choose diodes which will provide at least ± 350-mV forward voltage with the 100 µA supplied through R1.

It makes sense in the context of the design.

*But...*

Going to the diode datasheet and selection filter on Mouser and Digikey, I cannot find one diode that meets that requirement.

Furthermore I still have to find one diode where the datasheet mention Vf as such a low current. If someone knows a diode with Vf in order of ~300 mV at 100 uA forward current I will be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. All the answers were good and showed my lack of knowledge on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If someone knows a diode with Vf in order of ~300 mV at 100 uA forward current I will be glad to hear about it.

Pick any diode you have handy. Bias it forward through a 100k resistor to +11V from a power supply. Measure the forward diode voltage. If it's above 0.3V, you're good. And you will be good. Sometimes you just have to measure things to get a feel for how far from the requirement you are.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKRzSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Well, here I got a completely random diode from my junkbox:

[image: The diode bias circuit]
[image: Voltmeter readout of the forward voltage]

Since 0.488V > 0.3V, that diode would work. As would any one of similar size, as long as it's not a Zener diode.

Comment: Even a Zenner diode would work, they behave as normal diodes in the forward direction.

Comment: @KalleMP Yes indeed and it may even be a lower leakage diode than regular diodes just by the virtue of being a Zener!

Answer (score 11):

Just about any silicon small-signal diode such as 1N4148 will do at reasonable temperatures (just don't use Schottky diodes- they have low Vf at that current), but if you really want super-low leakage, use a couple jellybean BJTs connected as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwBjiV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For example, a couple of the erstwhile ubiquitous TO92 C1815 will typically leak less than 200nA at 80°C, compared to 1N4148 which will typically leak more than 36uA, so almost a factor of 200:1 better!

Comment: Is there a name for this arrangement of transistors?

Comment: Back-to-back diode-connected transistors.

Answer (score 9):

In order to meet the at least ±350 mV requirement the diode drop should be more than 350 mV @ 100 µA, not less.

Any common signal diode such as 1N4148/1N914 would meet that.

It is a very soft requirement.

The diodes should prevent the input to the opamp going beyond its allowable range of −1 V to V<sub>dd</sub> −0.3 V.

> Select the anti-parallel diodes. Choose diodes which will provide at least ±350-mV forward voltage with the 100 µA supplied through R1.

Answer (score 6):

From the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81139/1n4148w-g.pdf) this SMT version of the 1N4148 seems to have about 400 mV of forward drop at 100 uA, even over temperature.

However, the graph is for a "typical" device, so there's no guarantee over production quantities.  I don't know of any diodes that would spec a min/max Vf at 100 uA, so you may have to rely on the typical if you can't get the manufacturer to sign up for the spec you're looking for.

[image]